# bash [: too many arguments greater than symbol

Tags: bash, bash-completion

This isn't really a question (though I have one at the end), but rather a solution to a problem that I wanted to share in case it helps someone else.

For the longest time I had been getting `bash: [: too many arguments` when opening a new terminal (specifically iTerm2 on OS X with the bash-completion macport installed). This error originated from the line `if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" -a -n "$PS1" -a -z "$BASH_COMPLETION_COMPAT_DIR" ]; then` in the file `/opt/local/etc/bash_completion`. I have finally tracked down the problem to the fact that I had `export PS1='>'` in my `.bash_profile`. Changing PS1 to something else (e.g. `'> '`) fixes the problem with bash completion.

Some experimenting in OS X and Debian reveals that this problem occurs when adding extra expressions (with `-a` or `-o`) into a test (`[ ]`) after the expression involving `'>'`. E.g.,

```
> A='>'; if [ -n "$A" ]; then echo "yes"; fi
yes
> A='>'; if [ -n "$A" -a -n "$A" ]; then echo "yes"; fi
bash: [: too many arguments
> A='> '; if [ -n "$A" -o -n "$A" ]; then echo "yes"; fi
yes
> A='>'; if [ -n "$A" -o -n "Hello" ]; then echo "yes"; fi
bash: [: too many arguments
> A='>'; if [ -n "Hello" -a -n "$A" ]; then echo "yes"; fi
yes
```

Is this a (known) bug in bash?

Comment: I think it is due to the precedence of the "greater than" operator over the `-n` operator

Comment: Yet another reason to use the newer `[[]]` instead.

Comment: @edi9999 Surely the "greater than" should be interpreted as just a string? It works with `'> '` after all. (Which is why I wonder if this is a bug.)

@123 Yes, I would normally use `[[]]` instead, but this is in a script I didn't write (i.e. `bash_completion`) and I only control the `PS1` environment variable.

Comment: Incidentally, I just tried with a bunch of other symbols instead of `A='>'`. `>`, `<` and `=` all give this problem, while `?`, `|`, `#`, `%`, `/`, \, `,`, `;`, `:`, `\``, `"`, `!`, `-`, `+`, `[`, `]`, `{` and `}` don't.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I suggest you post your workaround _as an answer_, and then accept it yourself.

Comment: The other symbols are not operators recognized by `[`, in which case `[` doesn't expect another argument to follow them.

Comment: This isn't a bug in `bash` so much as a bug in the completion script; the POSIX standard recommends against using `-a` and `-o` precisely because of these types of ambiguities. `test` bases much of its interpretation of its arguments based on the number of arguments it receives, and using `-o/a` to combine expressions distorts the argument count.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your workaround is effective, as long as the string stored in `$A` is not an *operator* that `[` / `test` recognizes - simply adding a space is sufficient, as you've discovered.

> Surely the "greater than" should be interpreted as just a string? It works with '> ' after all.

No, the content of `$A` is *not* interpreted as just a string. (If you wanted that, you'd have to use `[[` instead, which is parsed in a special context, more like you'd expect from traditional programming languages.)

`[` (`test`) is a builtin (also exists as an external utility on most systems) and is therefore parsed with *command syntax*, which means:

- the shell performs its expansions *first* - `$A` references are replaced with the content of the variable in this case.
- the result is then passed to `[`

Thus, from the perspective of `[`, it doesn't matter whether or not the operator it ultimately sees - `>` in your example - came from a *literal* or was stored in a *variable*.

But note that *whitespace matters*: passing `>` (no spaces) is interpreted as an operator; `>`, by contrast, `><space>` is not - because that exact literal is *more* than just the operator.

---

The bottom line is:

- The bash-completion script you're using is *not robust*.
- As @chepner states in a comment on the question, [POSIX recommends not using `-o` / `-a`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) to avoid the ambiguity you encountered (emphasis mine):

> The XSI extensions specifying the **-a and -o** binary primaries and the '(' and ')' operators have been marked obsolescent. (Many expressions using them are **ambiguously defined** by the grammar depending on the specific expressions being evaluated.)

- Specifically, using separate `[ ... ]` expressions joined with `&&` (instead of `-a`) and `||` (instead of `-o`) solves the problem:

  ```
  [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ] && [ -n "$PS1" ] && [ -z "$BASH_COMPLETION_COMPAT_DIR" ]
  ```

Or, more simply, taking advantage of a non-empty string evaluating to true:

```
[ "$BASH_VERSION" ] && [ "$PS1" ] && [ -z "$BASH_COMPLETION_COMPAT_DIR" ]
```

---

Note that while `-a` and `-o` introduce *ambiguities*, they are *not* a *security concern* - you cannot inject arbitrary code through their use.

Comment: OK, so as @chepner says above, this is more of a bug in the completion script, than Bash itself. I'll mark this answer as correct then as it explains why the workaround I gave works. One more question though: is there then a potential for the expansion of $A to be used maliciously here or will it always just result in some kind of parsing error?

Comment: OK, great. Thanks for the extra clarification!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use two or more condition you should use

```
if [ condition1 ] && [condition2 ]
```

or

```
if [ condition1 ] || [condition2 ]
```

so in your case (first if "and"):

```
A='>'; if [ -n "$A" ] && [ -n "$A" ]; then echo "yes"; fi
```

for the "or" if:

```
A='>'; if [ -n "$A" ] || [ -n "Hello" ]; then echo "yes"; fi
```

But be aware that that the second check `[ -n "Hello" ]` is always true, so it's better to remove it.

You may be interested in [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/) to validate your bash script syntax.

Comment: Firstly, http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/classictest#misc_syntax documents the `-a` and `-o` syntax as an appropriate method for combining test expressions and they are widely used in existing bash scripts (hence my problem with bash completion).

Secondly, the `-n "Hello"` was just a simple always true expression that I was using to demonstrate my point. I wouldn't actually be using an expression like that for anything useful! :-P

Comment: @BrettRyland   yes you're right about -a and -o but I tried only to find an alternative and fast resolution to your issue. ;) btw I've updated the answer with -a and -o option as well

Comment: `[ ... ] -o [ ... ]` is just plain wrong; removing. Incidentally, `[ -n ">" ]` is fine because `test` recognizes that `>` is not an operator when it is the second of *two* arguments (ignoring the mandatory `]` argument).